# program ask input twice and send it to console allocConsole

Tags: c, windows, windows-console

I wrote a GUI program that can also be opened with arguments in a console.
When I ask for user input (a password) the program ask it twice. The first input is send to the console (obviously unrecognized) and the second is sent to my program.

```
if(!AttachConsole(ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS))
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
freopen("CONOUT$", "w", stdout);
freopen("CONOUT$", "w", stderr);
freopen("CONIN$", "r", stdin);

char var[10];
printf("before gets\n");
fgets(var,10,stdin);
printf("after gets\n");
printf("var : %s\n",var);
```

Is there a way to use the console then give it back to cmd.exe?

[image: Output in console window]

Comment: Have you tried `CreateFileA("CONIN$", ...`?

Comment: No.  You would have to use start /wait yourapp.exe to avoid the unwinnable race with cmd.exe.  Not practical, use AllocConsole() instead.  Or the obvious approach, a GUI app should use a window to accept user input.

Answer (score 1):

There's only one practical way to use the console and give it back, that is *be a console program*.

`devenv` (Visual Studio) does this in a clever way. The normal entry point is `devenv.exe` which is the expected GUI program, but there's a stub `devenv.com` that brokers the launch of devenv if launched from the console. This works because `.com` is tried before `.exe`.

Possible solution 1: use the com launcher to just launch the exe launcher and wait for it to terminate. Now `ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS` does what you want it to do.

Possible solution 2: Have the com process drive the `exe` process with a hidden window or something more exotic.

Possible solution 3: Have the entire application code in a `dll` that's loaded by both processes.